# dynamically populating a form's input field using the jquery .keypress() function has a delay?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to populate a form dynamically with the value of another form.

It works, sort of. However, there's a delay of some kind.

If I were to type "ABCDE" in field1, field2 would only populate the "ABCD". It never populates your last input. Why is this?

Sidenote: I'd like to eventually have something like 8 fields, and if you were to change any of them, all of the others would change and have the same input.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Azoruk/q4dwoc1y/

The html:

```
<input type="text" class="field1" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="field2" value=""/>
```

the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".field1").keypress(function(){
        $('.field2').val(
            $('.field1').val()
        );
  });
});
```

Comment: Or even better, use `input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery docs for [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> The `keypress` event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

So there may not be a good explanation as to *why* this unxpected behavior occurs because of how it is (or rather is not) implemented across different browsers. As noted, use `keyup` or `input` events instead.

```
$( '.field1' ).on( 'keyup', function( event ){
    $( '.field2' ).val(
        $( '.field1' ).val();
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".field1").keyup(function(){
        $('.field2').val(
            $('.field1').val()
        );
    });
});
```

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/vkriate/q4dwoc1y/1/)